# hide tabsheets by tabsheet caption or tabsheet name

Tags: delphi

is there any solution in Delphi to hide / unhide tabsheets in  a pagecontrol  not with this code

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to PageControl1.PageCount - 1 do
  begin
     PageControl1.Pages[i].TabVisible := False; // true to make it visible...
  end;
end;
```

but execute this Task while using the tabsheet names or the tabsheet caption

Comment: Certainly, TabSheet1.TabVisible := False; works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiding tabsheets is performed by setting the `TabVisible` property. That is the way to do it.

Perhaps what you are trying to do is identify a tabsheet by its caption. You can do that like this:

```
for i := 0 to PageControl1.PageCount - 1 do
  if PageControl1.Pages[i].Caption = TargetCaption then
    PageControl1.Pages[i].TabVisible := False;
```